# Reopening class or struct inside macro

Tags: crystal-lang

In "normal" code one can use `klass.is_a?(Reference.class)` to check whether or not a class was implemented with `class` or `struct`:

```
Array.is_a?(Reference.class) #=> true
Tuple.is_a?(Reference.class) #=> false
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to do the same in a macro to reopen said class/struct.

For example: if i pass the `Array` class to my macro, I need to generate code starting with `class Array`, whereas for a `Tuple` it needs to be `struct Tuple`.

I read the [docs for Crystal::Macros](https://crystal-lang.org/api/0.19.4/Crystal/Macros.html) over and over, but I'm not able to come up with code that does what I need and compiles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `<` to check this:

```
class MyClass
end

struct MyStruct
end

p {{ MyClass < Reference }}  # => true
p {{ MyClass < Struct }}     # => false
p {{ MyStruct < Struct }}    # => true
p {{ MyStruct < Reference }} # => false
```

However, I would recommend requiring users to use the macro inside said type. This way you don't need to reopen a class/struct because you are already inside it.

This is how many things in the standard library and the language are implemented. For example:

```
class Foo
  # it's not "include Foo, Bar" where "include" reopens the type
  include Bar 

  # It's not "JSON.mapping Foo, ..." where JSON.mapping reopens the type
  JSON.mapping(...) 
end
```

Comment: Thanks @asterite! My macro can be used in both ways, I have overloaded definitions for that: https://github.com/citizen428/protocols Even if I decide to remove that again, I actually learned quite a lot about Crystal trying to figure this out.

Answer (score 1):

[cjgajard](https://github.com/cjgajard) on [Gitter](https://gitter.im/crystal-lang/crystal) pointed out the following solution:

```
{% if Reference.all_subclasses.includes?(klass.resolve) %}
```